# Nested JSON Stringify wraps code in " and \. JSON Parse produces [object Object]

Tags: json, jsx, gatsby

I am using Gatsby and I am trying to use a `map` of an array to produce nested `JSON-LD` that validates with `schema.org`.

Code is:

```html
class TagRoute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const posts = this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
    const blogPostSchema = JSON.stringify(posts.map(post => (
      {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "BlogPosting",
      "name": `${post.node.frontmatter.title}`,
      'headline': `${post.node.frontmatter.title}`,
      "mainEntityOfPage": `https://example.com${post.node.fields.slug}`,
      "alternativeHeadline": `${post.node.frontmatter.title}`,
      "image": { 
        "@type": "imageObject", 
        "url": `https://example.com${
          !!post.node.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp ? post.node.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.fluid.src : post.node.frontmatter.image
        }`,
        "height": "640px",
        "width": "1280px"
        },
        "author": "Author Name",
        "genre": "SEO and Technical Marketing",
        "wordcount": `${post.node.fields.readingTime.words}`,
        "publisher": {
          "@type": "Organization",
          "name": "Author Name",
          "logo": {
          "@type": "imageObject",
          "url": `https://example.com/img/author.jpg`,
          "height": "200px",
          "width": "200px"
          },
          "mainEntityOfPage": "https://example.com",
          "sameAs": ["https://au.linkedin.com/in/social-account", "https://www.facebook.com/social-account/", "https://www.twitter.com/social-account/", "https://www.instagram.com/social-account/"],
          "url": "https://example.com"
        },
      "url": `https://example.com${post.node.fields.slug}`,
      "datePublished": `${ post.node.frontmatter.date }`,
      "dateModified": `${ post.node.frontmatter.date }`,
      "description": `${ post.node.frontmatter.description}`,
    })))
    const blogSchema = JSON.stringify(
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "Blog", 
        "author": "Author Name",
        "blogPosts": `${blogPostSchema}`,
      }
    )
    ... other stuff here
```

I end with with two end results.

**Result A) Nested JSON.Stringify:** Output becomes wrapped in quotations marks and added `\` in the result - no surprise, since it is nesting `JSON.Stringify()` which would wrap it in a string.
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/inkovic/16211da6722f34737653bccd234cc73e)
**Result B) JSON Parse returns [object Object]:** If I use `JSON.parse()` for the `const` or directly write the `this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(post => (...))` within the one `JSON.stringify()` function, it returns [object Object] instead of the values of the `JSON-LD` code.
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/inkovic/6493e5caeccac33e902c85985afe949e)

GraphQL as below, but it references the objects perfectly.

```html
export const tagPageQuery = graphql`
  query TagPage($tag: String) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 1000
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { tags: { in: [$tag] } } }
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 260)
          id
          html
          fields {
            slug
            readingTime {
              text
              words
            }
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            description
            image {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 2048, quality: 75) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                }
              }
            }
            templateKey
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

This `JSON.stringfy()` is close to valid `JSON+LD`, the quotations marks in the beginning and end of the array need to be stripped and all `\` need to be removed. But, I don't want to do string replacements to clean it up for valid code when there must be something wrong with how I am implementing the array in first place.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should avoid doing `JSON.stringify` twice? Since `blogPostSchema`'s a valid object, you can refer to it directly in `blogSchema`.

```js
const blogPostSchema = posts.map(post => ({ // no JSON.stringify here
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "BlogPosting",
  "name": post.node.frontmatter.title,
  ...
}))

const blogSchema = JSON.stringify({
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Blog", 
  "author": "Author Name",
  "blogPosts": blogPostSchema,  //  <--- refer to blogPostSchema directly
})
```

Comment: I did, but unfortunately it produces [object Object] as the output for `blogPostSchema` and I am not quite sure why. I attempted JSON.parse as well, which also produces [object Object]. It currently working by using a bunch of .replace(), .split(), .join() but that isn't ideal.